# Free software for Piping and Instrumentation Diagrams (P&ID)

Tags: gratis, drawing, cad

[Piping and instrumentation diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_instrumentation_diagram) are important documents in many engineering tasks. Is there a free or even open source program geared to this?

Where a proper P&ID software differs from a drawing tool like Visio or Diag is that the P&ID tool can output a parts list listing all components and connectors. Components and connecting lines can have additional specifications (like the power and type of a motor, or the size and material and pressure level of a pipe). This specifications can then be written to the material/component list.

If anyone has more working experience with P&ID software and thinks my specs are totally of the mark, please comment or edit accordingly.

[image: Sample of P&ID]

Comment: How can I embedd one of the pics from the wiki article?

Comment: If you do not have enough reputation to do that here, place your picture on an image hosting site and [edit] the link into your question. Somebody else will come along and edit the actual picture into it. As you can see two people have already edited your question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[AutoCad P&ID](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad-p-id/overview)

A free application for [educational use](http://www.autodesk.com/education/free-software/autocad-p-id). It achieves all you are after:

- Integration into Revit and automatic tagging and listing (Share databases, xrefs, and more)
- Faster P&ID drafting (Simple, in-context AutoCAD commands)
- Standard symbol libraries (PIP, ISA, JIS, and ISO/DIN are included)
- Data Validation tool (Quickly look for possible errors)

View more from their feature page [here](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad-p-id/features/all/gallery-view).

*Personally* I've also used [dia](http://dia-installer.de/) for P&IDs in the past, but it doesn't have any of the niceties you want.

Comment: AutoCAD P&ID [is no longer available](https://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad-p-id/overview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [freeCAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/) for the said purpose. There are many many other alternative to autoCAD and they are capable of P&ID among many other mechanical task.

There are many fine tutorial available in web created by subject expert and software player once you decided to go ahead with the software.

[image]

One simple example of manifold-like variable section pipe created via freeCAD.

Comment: Hello James! Your answer is a bit on the thin side. Could you elaborate a bit more as to how this tool serves the need of the OP? Maybe add a screenshot of a P&ID in freeCAD or a short guide on how to create one?

Comment: can you elaborate on wether freeCAD can export components lists, in the manner described in the question?

Comment: Will this help @Angelo Fuchs http://freecad-tutorial.blogspot.in/2012/05/variable-section-pipe.html

Comment: @JamesMascarenhas That looks good. Please [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/17508/edit) your question to contain that info. Please don't just add the link but write some text on your own so that the answer is still valuable if the link dies.

Comment: Sorry to reply so late, but this not at all what I need (though I think I understand the confusion). please consult the wiki page linked above for what a P&ID looks like. In a P&ID, you show that there's a tank and a pump and a pipe inbetween but not where everything is physically.

Comment: *Lacking the rep to comment, [mahmoud](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/16414/mahmoud) asks:* Can you elaborate on wether freeCAD can export components lists, in the manner described in the question?